# Xamarin embedded fragment in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, fragmentmanager

I'm having a heap of strange problems with fragments that contain fragments  embedded at design time in the axml.

My question is when I've finished with the fragment that I've loaded into a View with the FragmentManager, and then removed also using the FragmentManager, are the implicitly loaded fragments automatically destroyed? If not how should I clean up the parent fragment so that the embedded fragments are also drestroyed. Also when the parent fragment is destroyed do I need to call View.RemoveAllViews() to remove the fragments layout?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Capture the fragments as they are loaded into a list and then remove them when the main fragment is unloaded later. ( Must Dispose() )

```
public partial class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private LinearLayout LoaderLayout;

    private readonly List<Fragment> ActiveFragments = new List<Fragment>();

    public override void OnAttachFragment( Fragment fragment ) { ActiveFragments.Add( fragment ); }

    private async void ClearLoadFrame()
    {
        if( LoaderLayout == null )
            LoaderLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>( Resource.Id.loaderLayout );

        var Transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        foreach( var Frag in ActiveFragments )
        {
            Transaction.Remove( Frag );
            Frag.Dispose();
        }

        Transaction.CommitAllowingStateLoss();
        ActiveFragments.Clear();

        var Completed = false;

        RunOnUiThread( () =>
        {
            LoaderLayout.RemoveAllViews();
            Completed = true;
        } );

        await Task.Run( () =>
        {
            while( !Completed )
                Thread.Sleep(50);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not totally fixed. Now I have the inverse of the problem. When I create a fragment then destroy it and then try to recreate it I now get the embedded fragment throwing and exception saying that it cannot access a disposed object.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that what I'm trying to do isn't allowed.

[From this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)

> Note that one limitation is that nested (or child) fragments must be dynamically added at runtime to their parent fragment and cannot be statically added using the  tag.